# (Android) Global Interceptor for Android methods and classes?

Tags: java, android, logging, aop, aspectj

I need to implement extra log (anayltics) for all methods in my classes. 
So i need to add some global that executed before and after the method is called. Also i need to get that method & class name + method parameter input. I have already tried some aspectj libraries and plugins but they have some issue and not compatible with my application. Is there other way or library that is not based by aspectj for Android?